# How to include groups when adding new users to Active Directory using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a csv file which I am using to upload multiple users into the Active Directory. The groups column in this will contain multiple different entries. I want to be able to include this as part of my new user script.

I currently run a second script after the users have been created to apply groups to each user.

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\upload\testbulkupload2.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below

    $Username       = $User.username
    $Password       = $User.password
    $Firstname      = $User.firstname
    $Lastname       = $User.lastname
    $OU             = $User.ou #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
    $email          = $User.email
    $Password       = $User.Password


    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account

        #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$username@lon.cloud" `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
            -Path $OU `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -PasswordNeverExpires:$True

    }
}
```

and then I run

```
$user = 'username'
$groups = 'DRC VPN Users', 'Echo Prod Users'

foreach ($group in $groups) {

    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user

}
```

I am trying to get these as one script but have had no luck combining the two.

Comment: What is the format of the groups column inside the CSV. You could just create a new foreach loop inside the else statement of the first script. Also, you if statement can be simplified to if (Get-ADUser -Identity $Username)

Answer (score 0):

The `New-ADUser` cmdlet has a lot of parameters, but there is no parameter to set the group membership.
This needs to be done after the user is created like below.

I have changed the code somewhat and used [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) for better reading and to avoid having to use the hard-to-see backtick.
Also, there is no need to capture all fields from the CSV file into variables first. Just use them directly for the parameters.

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\upload\testbulkupload2.csv
$groups  = 'DRC VPN Users', 'Echo Prod Users'

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    # Read user data from each field in each row
    # the username is used more often, so to prevent typing, save that in a variable
    $Username       = $User.username

    # Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F "SamAccountName -eq '$Username'") {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else {
        # User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account

        # Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file

        # create a hashtable for splatting the parameters
        $userProps = @{
            SamAccountName        = $username
            UserPrincipalName     = '{0}@lon.cloud' -f $username
            GivenName             = $User.firstname
            Surname               = $User.lastname
            Name                  = '{0} {1)' -f $User.firstname, $User.lastname
            DisplayName           = '{0}, {1}' -f $User.lastname, $User.firstname
            Path                  = $User.ou  # This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
            EmailAddress          = $User.email
            AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.password -AsPlainText -Force) 
            Enabled               = $true
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
            PasswordNeverExpires  = $true
        }

        New-ADUser @userProps

        # add the new user to the groups here
        foreach ($group in $groups) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $username
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Note that the `Add-ADGroupMember` can take an array of usernames in the `-Members` parameter to add users in bulk, but in this case I would not advice doing that to avoid error messages when users are already present in AD (so you did not create them in the code above)</sup>